# How can I reconnect the restarted peer to the peers' network correctly with Hyperledger v1.0 alpha?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I followed the procedure of Quickstart in the link below to setup the peers' network with Hyperledger v1.0 alpha.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/quickstart.html

In the procedure, using "docker-compose up" to boot the four peer node as follows.

```
hlfv1 git:(master) ✗ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
76ac234a65ed        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha      "peer node start -..."   30 seconds ago      Up 28 seconds       0.0.0.0:7056->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7058->7053/tcp   peer1
5075165661f3        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha      "peer node start -..."   32 seconds ago      Up 29 seconds       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0
1955163b6e3d        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha   "orderer"                34 seconds ago      Up 31 seconds       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer0
65f4ad3217db        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   34 seconds ago      Up 31 seconds       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerOrg1
```

After the four peer node booted, I used docker command to stop and start the peer.

> docker stop peer1
>   docker start peer1

Then I executed the composer command to deploy business archive as follows .

> composer network deploy --archiveFile marbles-network@0.0.8.bna -p
>   hlfv1 --enrollId admin --enrollSecret adminpw

It says ...

> Error: Error: Invalid results returned ::NOT_FOUND

And also I can see the errors in the log of each peer.

> 2017-05-21 12:36:25.239 UTC [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 03a Error
>   during Chat, stopping handler: stream error: code = 1 desc = "context
>   canceled"

Without restarting the peer , the network is still OK and I can deploy business archive correctly.
How can I reconnect the restarted peer to the peers' network correctly with Hyperledger v1.0 alpha?

Comment: have you tried using the docker-compose command to stop and start services rather than the docker command ? docker-compose sets up a network specific to the containers it manages within that compose file

Comment: Yes, I've also tried using docker-compose command to stop and start service but result was the same... After I stopped any of the hyperledger services by using docker command or docker-compose command, I couldn't find the way to reconnect the service to peers' network.

Comment: This looks like a generic Hyperledger Fabric question, rather than something specific to Composer.

Comment: Thanks, I will delete the Hyperledger-composer tag.